# How to query for documents with an array attribute that is contained in a given array

Tags: mongodb

I want to query mongodb for documents that contain an array such that all of its elements are members of a given user-supplied array. In other words, I need to select documents whose array is a subset of a given array. For example, if I have this collection:

```
> db.foos.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4fe3901d0add2727c3adc7ca"), "tags" : [ "a", "b", "c" ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4fe390220add2727c3adc7cb"), "tags" : [ "a", "b" ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4fe390250add2727c3adc7cc"), "tags" : [ "a" ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4fe390250add2727c3adc7cd"), "tags" : [ "c" ] }
```

And my code was given the array `["a", "b", "z"]`, I want a query that produces the following result:

```
> db.foos.find( THE_QUERY! )
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4fe390220add2727c3adc7cb"), "tags" : [ "a", "b" ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4fe390250add2727c3adc7cc"), "tags" : [ "a" ] }
```

And these documents were selected because both `["a", "b"]` and `["a"]` are subsets of `["a", "b", "z"]`.

Answer (score 0):

*This answer does not solve the OPs issue. As per the comments, the needed feature is not currently present in MongoDB. I am leaving this up for a history of comments*

You want to use the [$in advanced query](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-%24in):

> The $in operator is analogous to the SQL IN modifier, allowing you to
>   specify an array of possible matches.

This would say: "Any foos document that has a tags value in this given array"

```
db.foos.find({tags: {$in: ["a", "b", "z"]}})
```

If you wanted to find any document that specifically intersects all elements with a given array, you can use [$all](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-%24all):

> The $all operator is similar to $in, but instead of matching any value
>   in the specified array all values in the array must be matched.

This would say: "Any foos document having a tags array containing all of these elements"

```
db.foos.find({tags: {$all: ["a", "b", "z"]}})
```

Comment: @WesFreeman: I changed it to the $in operator. For some reason I glanced at his examples wrong and thought he wanted an intersection.

Comment: $in also doesn't do what he wants, because it returns the document with "c"

Comment: @WesFreeman: Ah. Well then I suppose the answer is, there is no operator for this.

Comment: Nothing simple. I'm trying to work out how to do it with the aggregation framework.

Comment: This is not possible until 2.2, doing it with the aggregation framework should be cumbersome for such a simple query, you'd be better off just filtering it client side.

Comment: Yes, $all isn't enough because it is equivalent to test if the array query parameter is contained in the document's array. I want the opposite, to test if the document's array is contained in the query parameter array.

Comment: I was hoping that perhaps somehow negating the query and creating a more complex expression with $and and $or would do the trick.

Comment: @Sammaye do you have more information on what 2.2 feature would help me out? thanks

Comment: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-828 it is actually in the nightly so you could try it out now, but it won't be stable until 2.2

Comment: @Sammaye https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-828 looks like a useful feature, but I don't know how it applies to this problem. I ask because if there is hope to be able to do this query in the near (or close to near) future, I probably can get by with a slow client-side solution for now.

Comment: If you look at its description it allows you query an array within your document and only get those elements back that match. I know the title is terrible but it is what your looking for I think.

Comment: As far as I understood it, SERVER-828 will enable more control on the parts of the documents being returned. If we were talking about relational dbs, we would say it's a feature related to Projection. But my need is related to Selection, how to specify the set of documents that should be returned.

Comment: Im sorry I don't quite understand the difference, you want to show docs whose array sub elements only contain what your querying for and to only return what you queried for despite the fact that the array sub element may also contain other elements that do not match wher normally in MOngo it would mean it would return the whole root document.

Comment: Ok I think I understand. You want all documents which have a subset that matches the array but the subsetmay not always be complete and you dont wanna get docs that have more than the subset. No this JIRA is not related to that, sorry.